# How to connect pictureboxes with connecting line

Tags: c#, winforms

first sorry for my English. I am programming application in windows forms. It is something like Packet Tracer. I have four buttons. When I click on them, they dynamicaly create pictureboxes with picture of Router or Switch,.... Each time I click on the button, new picture box(Switch or Router,...), is created. I can also move with this pictureboxes by mouse. 
I need to create a button, which connects selected pictureboxes with line(Cable). This pictureboxes should be selected by click on them. It sholud be able to move with this objects(movable line).
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;

        PictureBox[] picturebox = new PictureBox[100];



        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void router_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            ++a;

            picturebox[a] = new PictureBox();
            picturebox[a].Name = "picturebox" + a;
            picturebox[a].Location = new Point(0 + (a-1) *100,100);
            picturebox[a].Size = new Size(70, 70);
            picturebox[a].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            picturebox[a].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.Controls.Add(picturebox[a]);


            picturebox[a].Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\\router.jpg");
            picturebox[a].Refresh();
            picturebox[a].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseDown);
            picturebox[a].MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseMove);
            picturebox[a].MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseUp);




        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        bool drag = false;

        private void picMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get original position of cursor on mousedown
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
            drag = true;
        }

        private void picMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (drag)
            {
                PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
                // Get new position of picture
                pb.Top += e.Y - y;
                pb.Left += e.X - x;
                pb.BringToFront();
            }
        }

        private void picMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            drag = false;
        }

        private void switch1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ++b;
            picturebox[b] = new PictureBox();
            picturebox[b].Name = "picturebox" + b;
            picturebox[b].Location = new Point(0 + (b - 1) * 100, 180);
            picturebox[b].Size = new Size(70, 70);
            picturebox[b].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            picturebox[b].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.Controls.Add(picturebox[b]);


            picturebox[b].Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\HP ProBook 450\Desktop\Grafika\switch1.png");
            picturebox[b].Refresh();
            picturebox[b].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseDown);
            picturebox[b].MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseMove);
            picturebox[b].MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseUp);



        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ++c;

            picturebox[c] = new PictureBox();
            picturebox[c].Name = "picturebox" + c;
            picturebox[c].Location = new Point(0 + (c - 1) * 100, 260);
            picturebox[c].Size = new Size(70, 70);
            picturebox[c].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            picturebox[c].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.Controls.Add(picturebox[c]);


            picturebox[c].Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\HP ProBook 450\Desktop\pc.jpg");
            picturebox[c].Refresh();
            picturebox[c].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseDown);
            picturebox[c].MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseMove);
            picturebox[c].MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseUp);

        }

        private void server_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ++d;

            picturebox[d] = new PictureBox();
            picturebox[d].Name = "picturebox" + d;
            picturebox[d].Location = new Point(0 + (d - 1) * 100, 340);
            picturebox[d].Size = new Size(70, 70);
            picturebox[d].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            picturebox[d].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.Controls.Add(picturebox[d]);


            picturebox[d].Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\HP ProBook 450\Desktop\server.png");
            picturebox[d].Refresh();
            picturebox[d].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseDown);
            picturebox[d].MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseMove);
            picturebox[d].MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseUp);

        }




    }
}
```

THank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invalidate the parent when you add a picturebox or when you move a picturebox:
(`picMouseMove` and 4 times in the `click` handlers, it would be better to use 1 function)

```
    Invalidate();
```

This is an example OnPaint, drawing lines between the pictureboxes as they are located in the Controls collection: (your picturebox array seems very weird, you always add controls at index 1, always overwriting the previous entry?! i'd suggest using a List if you need to keep a reference to them)

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        var pictureBoxes = Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();
        if (pictureBoxes.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < pictureBoxes.Length; i++)
            {
                DrawLineBetween(e.Graphics, pictureBoxes[i - 1], pictureBoxes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

This function can be used to draw a line between 2 of your boxes:

```
    private void DrawLineBetween(Graphics g, PictureBox from, PictureBox to)
    {
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black,
            new Point(from.Left + from.Width / 2, from.Top + from.Height / 2),
            new Point(to.Left + to.Width / 2, to.Top + to.Height / 2));
    }
```

----- full sample below -----

I refactored your full example, and added the code above to start you off with a working example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<PictureBox> pictureboxes = new List<PictureBox>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddPictureBox(string imagePath)
        {
            var pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Name = "picturebox" + pictureboxes.Count;
            pb.Location = new Point(pictureboxes.Count * 100, 100);
            pb.Size = new Size(70, 70);
            pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.Controls.Add(pb);

            pb.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
            pb.Refresh();
            pb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseDown);
            pb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseMove);
            pb.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseUp);

            pictureboxes.Add(pb);

            Invalidate();
        }

        private void router_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddPictureBox(@"D:\\router.jpg");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        bool drag = false;

        private void picMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get original position of cursor on mousedown
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
            drag = true;
        }

        private void picMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (drag)
            {
                PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
                // Get new position of picture
                pb.Top += e.Y - y;
                pb.Left += e.X - x;
                pb.BringToFront();

                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void picMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            drag = false;
        }

        private void switch1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddPictureBox(@"D:\HP ProBook 450\Desktop\Grafika\switch1.png");
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddPictureBox(@"D:\HP ProBook 450\Desktop\pc.jpg");
        }

        private void server_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddPictureBox(@"D:\HP ProBook 450\Desktop\server.png");
        }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            if (pictureboxes.Count > 1)
            {
                var arr = pictureboxes.ToArray();
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    DrawLineBetween(e.Graphics, arr[i - 1], arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void DrawLineBetween(Graphics g, PictureBox from, PictureBox to)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black,
                new Point(from.Left + from.Width / 2, from.Top + from.Height / 2),
                new Point(to.Left + to.Width / 2, to.Top + to.Height / 2));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But, I need to create a new button(line), on which I click, I can connect with line any pictureboxes what I want.